# How to calculate the cross-correlation of a halfwave?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying working on a vehicle modle and testing it with steering maneuvres standardised by the ISO. When it comes to data analysis the ISO standard says the following:

> 6.4 Time lag and Sine Time lag
>    The time lags between the variables steering wheel angle, yaw velocity, lateral acceleration, etc. are
>   calculated for the first and second peak by cross-  correlation of the
>   first and second halfwaves respectively.

So i looked up the definition of the cross-correlation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). The definition says the TAU is the lag itself. So how do i calculate the lag using the "cross-correlation the first and second halfwaves" when the crosscorrelation needs the lag to be calculated?
PS: I tagged this as convolution, because there is no cross-correlation tag and this seemed to be the closest thing to me. Feel free to re-tag if wrong.

EDIT:
Okay I'll try to explain a little more: The maneuvre of the ISO standard is a driving maneuvre with a one-period sinusoid Steeringwheelangle input (so i guess the halfwaves are the half periods of the sinusoid output). Now i made simulations with this maneuvre and want to analise the data the way that the standard is telling me to. What i quoted you there is all the information, that the standard provides at this place. But yes, i guess they are talking about the delay between the beginning of like steering input and the beginning of the raise of the yaw velocity for example. That's what i should calculate via the cross correlation.

Comment: i added signal-processing and mathematical-modeling, i hope that fits

Comment: You should put a little more of context Max to better understand the problem. What is a halfwave in this problem? What kind of information do you want to extract from the variables? I guess that the term "time lags" in the problem are not the same that the independient variable of the crosscorrelation function, may be a kind of time delays? Take a look to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/cross-correlation-of-delayed-signal-in-noise.html) example to know what I am taking about.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza I tried to provide you with more information. Does this help you to help me? I'm kind of overwhelmed by the problem, and don't even really know, what is important to solve it.